# Solving inequalities with modulus in addition

Tags: inequality

How would you solve an inequality with modulus in addition?

Question is:
$$|2x-1| + |x-3| \geq 10$$

How to start here?

What I tried:
Well you can obviously solve the equation for each possibility of the terms. Meaning that just take out the modulus and take each case. However, is there an easier way to do it? Without having to solve separately for each case? That is very time consuming.

What I did:
Consider both are positive
$$3x - 4 \geq 10$$
$$x = 14/3$$

Consider both are negative
$$-3x + 4 \geq 10$$
$$x \leq 14/3$$

Consider one negative and other positive alternatively:
$$-x-2 \geq 10$$
$$x \leq -12$$
$$x \ geq 12$$

You can obviously see a pattern here. But how to get the two numbers $14/3$ and $12$??

Comment: The only way that I see to do it is by doing each case separately. However, you only really need to change the left side for two cases: (1) the arguments of the absolute values the same sign and (2) the arguments of the absolute values different signs. To get the two other possible cases, simply multiply the right side by $-1$ and flip the inequality. It still will be pretty time-consuming, but it's a rote procedure.

Comment: @MorganO That's another way to do it I guess. But its more or less the same. There has to be an easier way to do it. By the way, what are you getting as an answer?

Comment: Yes, it's more or less the same. I haven't solved it out -- why don't you edit your post to show your work and I'll check it for you?

Comment: Okay. Sure. Just give me a sec.

Comment: By inspection the "middle case" $x$ between $1/2$ and $3$ will not give a solution.

Comment: Yep but how does that help in the question? @AndréNicolas

Comment: One less case to worry about.

Comment: I see. But still doesn't give us the answer. @AndréNicolas

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** separate the cases:

- $x<\frac12$
- $\frac 12<x<3$ and
- $x>3.$

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Gummybears I edited, better?

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of arithmetic errors.

For the first one case, you probably don't want equality for your solution.

In the second case, check what happens when you subtract $4$ from both sides and divide by $-3$.

The third case looks good.

In order not to check the "opposite" combination of positive/negative after the third case -- i.e. to skip checking the case $2x-1\geq 0$ and $x-3 \leq 0$ -- you need to say something about why this will not yield any  possible solutions (or just calculate it out).

Also think about how to put all the cases together to describe the solution set (that is, all values for which the inequality holds).